# Need help searching video files by encoding format profile

Tags: codec, file-search

I am looking for a way to search all my video files (directory/recursive) that have a "Format profile" of QuickTime and/or "Codec ID" of qt.

I just found out that my encoding software has occasionally been using QuickTime when it was supposed to use standard iso Base Media. I would like to search all my files to see how many were affected.

Selecting each files and using MediaInfo does tell me which codec was used, but going though each individual file seems overly excessive.

Does anyone know of a search program (or a simple batch) that returns results based on the encoding method, or that can read the information supplied by MediaInfo and create a list based on that?

Comment: how many items are in a "folder" or is it 1 folder for each 1 item?  MediaInfo will do folders (not all subs too easily), and editing a "sheet" you can get any data you want to show in it, although it is not always simple because of the quantiy of things that can be shown.  That is the method i would use for the same thing.

Comment: Several folders, several items in each

Answer (score 2):

You can use MediaInfo command line version and:

`mediainfo "--Inform=General;%CompleteName%,%Format%,%Format_Profile%,%CodecID%\r\n" YourDirectoryName >List.csv`

Then open List.csv in yoyr prefered spreadsheet processor.

Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo

Comment: Perfect!! Exactly what I needed. Thanks Jérôme